# Proving $|h(x)|\leq (Mx^2)/2$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $h:[0,a]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be twice differentiable, $h'(0)=h(0)=0$, and $|h''(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in [0,a]$.

I proceed with the mean value theorem, but I do not have the factor of $1/2$ in the result above (I get$|g(x)|\leq (Mx^2)$). Does anyone have any hints? This is my first time asking on here. I can provide a little more detail about my proof if wanted.

Comment: Results have hypotheses. What are they?

Comment: It follows very quickly by integrating (though with the assumptions given, you need the generalized Riemann integral to be sure that $h$ is integrable)